# How to add new network block to wpa_supplicant in command line?

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I want to add network block into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_suppplicant.conf` file.

The original file looks like,

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="HOMEWIFI"
    psk="12345678"
}
```

and I would like to add new network block in command line, finally the file would be :

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="HOMEWIFI"
    psk="12345678"
}

network={
    ssid="NEW_WIFI"
    psk="00000000"
}
```

I want to do this not manual, but **command line**.

I red https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant this, 
so If I run this

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -i interface -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
# wpa_cli 
> scan
OK
> scan_results
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "NEW_WIFI"
> set_network 0 psk "0000000"
> enable_network 0
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection completed.
> save_config
OK
```

will add new network block successfully.

But I believe there is more easy and simple way. That above way takes time, and looks verbose. Is there more elegant and simple way to do it?

Comment: [`man wpa_cli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/wpa_cli.8.html) says it can execute commands given as arguments (e.g., `wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid NEW_WIFI`). That should be easily scriptable. There's also the `-a` option, which you might find interesting.